# Reordering pandas dataframe data for a multiindex after pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I'm building an analysis tool for public transportation data and want to reorder data in a pandas dataframe that can be best explained using the following example:

My initial shape of data is:

```
            Population                                GDP per capita
date        2015          2016          2017          2015            2016            2017
country                        
France      66593366.0    66859768.0    67118648.0    40564.460707    41357.986933    42850.386280
Germany     81686611.0    82348669.0    82695000.0    47810.836011    48943.101805    50638.890964
Italy       60730582.0    60627498.0    60551416.0    36640.115578    38380.172412    39426.940797
Spain       46444832.0    46484062.0    46572028.0    34818.120507    36305.222132    37997.852337
```

I wan't to reshape the dataframe so that the dates are the toplevel index and the currently lower level information `Population` and `GDP per capita` is on the lower level. The resulting dataframe should look as follows:

```
            2015                            2016                            2017
date        Population    GDP per capita    Population    GDP per capita    Population    GDP per capita
country
France      66593366.0    40564.460707      66859768.0    41357.986933      67118648.0    42850.386280
Germany     81686611.0    47810.836011      82348669.0    48943.101805      82695000.0    50638.890964
Italy       60730582.0    36640.115578      60627498.0    38380.172412      60551416.0    39426.940797
Spain       46444832.0    34818.120507      46484062.0    36305.222132      46572028.0    37997.852337
```

How can I achieve this using pandas? I've been experimenting with `swaplevel` but was not able to get the expected results.

The dataframe is obtained from the following data with a `pivot` operation:

```
       country    date    Population    GDP per capita    GNI per capita

1      Germany    2017    82695000.0    50638.890964    51680.0
2      Germany    2016    82348669.0    48943.101805    49770.0
3      Germany    2015    81686611.0    47810.836011    48690.0
60     Spain      2017    46572028.0    37997.852337    37990.0
61     Spain      2016    46484062.0    36305.222132    36300.0
62     Spain      2015    46444832.0    34818.120507    34740.0
119    France     2017    67118648.0    42850.386280    43790.0
120    France     2016    66859768.0    41357.986933    42020.0
121    France     2015    66593366.0    40564.460707    41100.0
237    Italy      2017    60551416.0    39426.940797    39640.0
238    Italy      2016    60627498.0    38380.172412    38470.0
239    Italy      2015    60730582.0    36640.115578    36440.0
```

And the following `pivot`:

```
df_p = df_small.pivot(
    index='country', 
    columns='date', 
    values=['Population', 'GDP per capita'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Swap levels and sort_index,

```
df_p.columns = df_p.columns.swaplevel(1,0)
df_p = df_p.sort_index(axis = 1)


date    2015                        2016                        2017
        GDP per capita  Population  GDP per capita  Population  GDP per capita  Population
country                     
France  40564.460707    66593366.0  41357.986933    66859768.0  42850.386280    67118648.0
Germany 47810.836011    81686611.0  48943.101805    82348669.0  50638.890964    82695000.0
Italy   36640.115578    60730582.0  38380.172412    60627498.0  39426.940797    60551416.0
Spain   34818.120507    46444832.0  36305.222132    46484062.0  37997.852337    46572028.0
```

Answer (score 1):

At a broad level, you want to do something like this:

```
df.pivot(index='country', columns='date', values=['GDP per capita' , 'Population']) \
    .reorder_levels(['date', None], axis=1) \  # the multiindex doesn't get a name, so None
    .sort_index(level=[0, 1], axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
```

First, you do the pivot. Then, reorder the levels to put the date at the top. That creates something that isn't quite right though, where the MultiIndex then provides an entry for every single element.

So second, sort the columns index by its levels to group them. And you end up with this:

```
date           2015                       2016                       2017               
         Population GDP per capita  Population GDP per capita  Population GDP per capita
country                                                                                 
France   66593366.0   40564.460707  66859768.0   41357.986933  67118648.0   42850.386280
Germany  81686611.0   47810.836011  82348669.0   48943.101805  82695000.0   50638.890964
Italy    60730582.0   36640.115578  60627498.0   38380.172412  60551416.0   39426.940797
Spain    46444832.0   34818.120507  46484062.0   36305.222132  46572028.0   37997.852337
```

Also, it'd be great to find a way to easily read in your data instead of having to gerrymander out a system using `pd.read_csv(string_io_obj, sep='\s\s+')` but that's just a minor quibble.

By passing explicit sorting instructions for both levels, you can also make `level=1` for the columns have reverse order to get Population before per cap GDP. That might not work in other cases where someone may want explicit ordering that is not coincidentally alphabetic (or the reverse thereof).